# Asm ClassReader accept

Tags: java, assembly, java-bytecode-asm

I am using Asm to visit the java byte code to get the method infomation.It seems that accept method of  class ClassReader is called in a asynchronized manner.So it is impossible to obtain method infomation immediately.What can I do ?

Answer (score 1):

Actually,  the accept method is called from your own code and you shoult pass your ClassVisitor implementation. Then methods of that visitor will be called and when call toaccept completes all information about class is passed trough that visitor. You can record it in some visitor's member fields or process imediately. If you need in-memory model of your class, you can use ClassNode as such visitor.